# jquery this.each is not function when using .val

Tags: jquery, html, materialize

i'm trying to put range's value in Text Box with jquery
but i got error with "Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function"

[image]

This is my code

```
<body class="bg valign-wrapper">
<div class="container row center-align">
    <div class="card">
    <span class="card-title"><br><h3>Simulasi</h3></span>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="main.html">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field">
                <input type="number" id="dp" class="">
                <label class="active" for="nama">Nominal DP</label>
            </div>
            <p class="range-field">
              <input type="range" id="rangedp" min="0" max="100">
            </p>
        </div>
        <button style="width" class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue" type="submit" name="signin">Submit
                    <i class="material-icons left">send</i>
                </button><br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#rangedp").change(function(){
            $("#dp").val($("#rangedp").val);
            console.log($(this).val);
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select").formSelect();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: 1.`.val` needs to be `.val()` everywhere in your code.2. unable to see `.each` in your current code

Comment: should be closed as a small typo error to be honest. But yes. In jQuery the syntax is `.val()` and in pure JS it's `.value`. As @AlivetoDie pointed out, we are unable to see the `.each` part of your application. If there is any further issues, please edit that part into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $("#dp").val($("#rangedp").val);
```

should be

```
 $("#dp").val($("#rangedp").val());
```

The rest, with the code so far, you should dig yourself or share code.

Comment: this is one issue but not the actual issue what OP is facing

Answer (score 0):

The following code is running formSelect() on select elements via the Materialize library, of which there are none present on the page. I'm assuming Materialize is trying to iterate through them, which could be why you're seeing this error.

```
$("select").formSelect();
```

Remove this line & see [this page](https://materializecss.com/select.html).